# Why don't I have permission to open a file in my documents?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

In Windows 7, I am trying to open a file in my documents. When I do, I get the error message:

> You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or
>   an administrator to obtain permission.

What I have tried:

- I have tried restarting and taking ownership of the file.
- I logged on from the Administrator account and still couldn't open or modify
  it.
- I can modify every other file in the folder.

This problem first started occurring after I saved it in Photoshop. All of a sudden I could no longer overwrite the file or open it in any other program.

I cannot open it in FileAssasin because I get the error message as I explained, even when running as admin. If I copy the path in to FileAssassin, I get the error:

> The file you have specified does not exists or is not visible to
>   FileASSASIN. Please select another file.

Any ideas? I would really rather not install some sort of bootable file deletion program or Linux, it doesn't seem worth it just to delete one file.

Comment: Good description of the problem and what you've tried. Have you tried accessing the file in Safe Mode?

Comment: Is your post about why you don't have permission, or simply about how to get rid of the file, or both? For deletion, try `del "\\?\Drive:\Path to\file.ext"` from an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

> The file you have specified does not exists or is not visible to FileASSASIN.

So maybe your problem is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1064984/file-exists-but-not-visible-from-other-programs). There is an answer there which may be useful.